# SSIS Script Task: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, azure-blob-storage, etl

I'm working on a SSIS project using SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) with Visual Studio 2015 and I'm referencing the dll Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll in a Script Task and using C# on my project but it keeps throwing the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have already tried to Unblock the DLL using Windows PowerShell, registering the dll on Windows, checked if I had copied the dll into bin directory on my project folder, but no results at all.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        string srcBlob = (string) Dts.Variables["User::dBlobName"].Value;
        // Substitui o nome da pasta PROCESSAR para PROCESSADOS
        string destBlobName = srcBlob.Replace((string)Dts.Variables["$Project::dSrcBlobDirectory"].Value, (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::dDestBlobDirectory"].Value);
        string srcContainerName = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::dBlobContainer"].Value;
        string accountName = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::dStorageAccountName"].Value;
        //byte[] storageAccessKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string) Dts.Variables["$Project::dStorageAccessKey"].Value);
        string storageAccessKey = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::dStorageAccessKey"].Value;

        MoveBlobInSameStorageAccount(accountName, storageAccessKey, srcContainerName, srcBlob, destBlobName);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    static void MoveBlobInSameStorageAccount(string accountName, string accountKey, string containerName, string sourceBlobName, string destBlobName)
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sourceContainer = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobName);
        var destinationContainer = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var destinationBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(destBlobName);
        destinationBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
        sourceBlob.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
    }
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `HttpClient` to invoke the Blob Storage REST API before. Based on your description, you are using [Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs), I assumed that the assembly could not load correctly, since it is not in the GAC. You may need to leverage an [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler for loading the assembly, more detailed tutorial, you could refer to [How to load an Assembly in a SSIS script task that isn’t in the GAC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/).

Comment: You are the best! Thank you!

Comment: Try to delete the assembly reference and then add it back - I had some issues with wrong version being referenced for unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

You can add dlls (including Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll) to the Azure SSIS runtime, as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

Thank you [Geri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9740791/geri222) for doing the research: [Script task to upload zip file to blob storage with azure datafactory SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209142/script-task-to-upload-zip-file-to-blob-storage-with-azure-datafactory-ssis)