# Script task to upload zip file to blob storage with azure datafactory SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a azure data factory project. I need to query some data from my Azure SQL Database then load into an xml, zip it and upload to blob sotrage. I don't want to write anything to the file system (because I think the Azure Database doesn't have any lcoal storage) so I am using the Memorystream.

This Script Task is working on my local SSIS database but not on the Azure Datafactory:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Azure;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;


public void Main()
    {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = null;


        try
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("FullList");
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("CustomerTable");
            oleDa.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::CustomerSelect"].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            DataTable dt_product = new DataTable("ProductTable");
            oleDa.Fill(dt_product, Dts.Variables["User::ProductSelect"].Value);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt_product);



            DataRelation relation = ds.Relations.Add("relation", ds.Tables["CustomerTable"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["ProductTable"].Columns["id"]);
            relation.Nested = true;


            string connstring = Dts.Connections["testolgdev"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction).ToString();
            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connstring, out storageAccount))
            {
                try
                {
                    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();


                    cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("flat");

                    string fileName = "xml" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".zip";
                    var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                    using (var stream = new ZipArchive(blob.OpenWrite(), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                    {
                        var entry = stream.CreateEntry("test_dataset_fullresult_onlymem.xml");
                        using (var es = entry.Open())
                        {
                            ds.WriteXml(es);
                        }


                    }



                }
                catch (StorageException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error returned from the service: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong connection string");
            }



        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException e)
        {

            throw;
        }

  Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

**This is the Azure Datafactory SSIS error when I deploy and execute it:** 
Script Task 1:Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is it possible to fix this? Can I add the missing dll to Azure Datafactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this guide I can add the missing dlls to Azure-SSIS IR: 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup)

Thanks to **Sandy Winarko(MSFT)** for the answer!